# Computing probability of proportions of (possibly) overlapping sets

Tags: probability, modeling, model-selection, missing-data

Consider $n$ *fixed* subsets of a finite universe $U$:  $A,B,C,D,\ldots$

Then let $Coll$ be the collection of sets we get from the closure of the set $\{U,A,B,C,D, \ldots\}$ under the operations $\cup,\cap$ and set-theoretic difference.

(As an aside, to help picture Coll, note that $|Coll|≤ 2^{2^n}$  Imagine an n-ary Venn diagram partitioning U into 2ⁿ disjoint pieces--there are then 2^(2ⁿ) combinations of the pieces, which will be distinct if the 2ⁿ pieces are all nonempty.)

I am looking for methods to estimate the size of a given element of $Coll$ given *some* of the sizes of other sets in $Coll$.  Specifically, I would like to know the probability distribution of the cardinalities of a given set in $Coll$, given *some* precise values for the sizes of some of the other sets in $Coll$.

I don't know what probability model is appropriate to use is no further information is known--what methods should I look to for this?

Comment: What information are you using to conclude that "on average, $|A\cap B|=1$"?  Indeed, what is the sense of "on average" being used here?

Comment: I don't know about "wise," but averaging in this way seems to have no objective foundation.  There is no reason to suppose that because you find three ways to describe the configurations, they must be equiprobable or have equal weights.  And there is the crux of the matter: without additional information, your *implicit* question is not answerable.  The *explicit* question invites us to name probability theory as the branch of statistical theory that deals with probability distributions--but that answer is self-evident from the term "probability" appearing at the beginning of the question.

Comment: You're not quite there.  Even if the cardinalities are equally likely, that does not imply the *sets* themselves are equally distributed conditional on their cardinalities.  It sounds like you want to stipulate that (a) you are drawing sets at random from some fixed set $U$; (b) the cardinalities are equally distributed; (c) conditional on the cardinality, all possibilities are equally distributed; (d) you draw $n$ such sets this way, *independently* of each other; and (e) for a given "logical combination" you want to know the distribution of its cardinality.  Is this correct?

Comment: I have revise this question entirely, please see the new question

Comment: Hi Adam. Is $U$ finite? Also, how do you get $|\mathrm{Coll}| = 2^{2^n}$? Suppose for example $U = \{1,2,3\}$, $A = \{1\}$ and $B = \{1,2\}$. So $n = 2$ and $2^{2^n} = 16$. However, there are only 8 possible subsets that can be generated by finite intersections unions and complements of $\{U,A,B\}$. You'll also need to specify some form of probability model to get an answer here. That piece is still missing. Cheers.

Comment: Sorry, U is finite I added that, and that is actually just an upper bound for |Coll| -- informally, consider a venn diagram for 3 sets--there are 2³ disjoint 'pieces' in the diagram, and if they are all non-empty you can form 2^⁽2³) sets out of them by logical operations.

I don't know what probability model I should use--I want the probability model that is most appropriate if no other information is known.